# converting from file path in a column to reference another table with an id number for a filepath

Tags: sql-server, database

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

I've been trying for weeks to get this sorted over my original question for getting a query to work, it does but not correctly. What I want to achieve from this is on the old questions table I'm getting data from has a "filepath" column that the question data refers to from a folder on the local machine this is structured as an example like this: (some columns I haven't included)

Old question table

```
QuizQuestionID  MasterQuestionID    MasterQuestionGUID                  MasterTypeID    MasterDifficultyID      MasterCategoryID    MasterDecadeID  QuizQuestionTypeID      QuizQuestionDifficultyID        QuizQuestionCategoryID          QuizQuestionDecadeI D   QuestionText                                            AnswerText              FilePath                                        IsEditable  IsDeletable IsDeleted   IsDifficultyOverridden    CreatedDate                   ModifiedDate                AUTO_UseCount    AUTO_TieBreakerUsageCount    AUTO_TieBreakerLastUsed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1222            1755                0bee472592ce78e7457d87d7a172ff7b    3               2                       7                   3               3                       2                               7                               3                       Name the singer.                                        David Essex             /Sounds/CHORUS David Essex - Tahiti.mp3         False       True        False       False                     2014-01-18 12:53:59.000       2014-02-07 12:28:55.000     0                NULL                         NULL
1223            1756                1df7bd191ef5e31b854c7de5f18982d0    1               2                       11                  NULL            1                       2                               11                              NULL                    What is this savoury item?                              Green Chili             /Images/General/Greeen Chili.png                False       True        False       False                     2014-01-18 15:17:39.000       2014-01-26 19:46:00.000     0                NULL                         NULL
```

Now in the new question table, a column uses another table called media2 to find the local filepath of files these are structured:

New question table

```
id      uuid                                    type    question                        answer          media   created_date                    modified_date                   created_user    modified_user       master_category     master_decade       master_difficulty       is_editable     is_deletable        multiple_choice         choice_1        choice_2        choice_3        choice_4        blur_effect     related     square_1        square_2        square_3        square_4        tie_breaker
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8033    07B3D24A-6FFA-40AF-B723-B78C9899D4B4    Audio   Name the singer.                David Essex     21488   2015-03-23 11:51:31.000         2016-03-08 15:21:48.697         NULL            NULL                7                   2                   1                       False           False               False                   NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL
17395   48E555BD-52D6-4358-89E5-8FEE0F0F3AFD    Text    What is this savoury item?      Green chili     19459   2013-09-10 23:51:35.460         2013-09-13 12:51:53.963         NULL            NULL                12                  NULL                1                       False           False               NULL                    NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL            NULL
```

Media2 table

```
id      UUID                                    name                                Path                                                                Mime/type   directory   used for    Category     folder     import folder
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21488   c25183d2-aad7-4c16-8869-9eac711cc39b    CHORUS David Essex - Tahiti Quiz    C:\media\audio\c25183d2-aad7-4c16-8869-9eac711cc39b.mp3             audio/mp3   Audio       Quiz        Audio        NULL       NULL
19459   642db3c3-c531-4818-9b0d-4d7ccd35e0f9    Green chili                         C:\media\images\642db3c3-c531-4818-9b0d-4d7ccd35e0f9.png            image/png   Images      Quiz        Images       NULL       NULL
```

Just need to add that "UUID" is a random set of numbers the table uses to identify the file name in their folders so we don't get any duplicated files that may be named the same but don't have the same content and are also used by other software apart from the quiz so I can't use this as a reference to create a query.

This is the whole code that converts the "old questions table" to the "new questions table" the substring is the part that converts the format from old to new which works fine but to clarify it returns null to the "media" column on any image or sound questions, its supposed to convert the filepath column from the old table against the "media2" table and then import all rows to the new question table with the "media" column referencing the "media2" table for filepaths.

```
--Specify the database, table and columns we want to insert into
 INSERT INTO NewDatabase.dbo.quizquestions (uuid, [type], question, answer, created_date, modified_date, master_category, master_decade, master_difficulty, is_editable, is_deletable, media)

--Get the data from the old database (old_database) and map the media filename to the media2 table in the new database

select 
   questions.uuid, 
   questions.newtype, 
   questions.QuestionText, 
   questions.AnswerText, 
   questions.CreatedDate, 
   questions.ModifiedDate, 
   questions.master_category, 
   questions.master_decade, 
   questions.master_difficulty,
   questions.IsEditable, 
   questions.IsDeletable, 
   media.id as mediaid from
(
   select NEWID() as uuid, 
   CASE 
          WHEN qqt.TypeName = 'Sound' THEN 'Audio'
          ELSE qqt.TypeName
   END AS newtype,
   qq.QuestionText, qq.AnswerText,  
   CASE 
       WHEN qq.createdDate is not NULL THEN qq.createdDate
          ELSE GETDATE()
   END as createdDate,
   CASE 
          WHEN qq.ModifiedDate is not NULL THEN qq.ModifiedDate
          ELSE GETDATE()
   END as ModifiedDate, 
   CASE

          WHEN cat.id is NOT NULL THEN cat.id
          ELSE 1
   END as master_category,
   qqdc.QuizQuestionDecadeID as master_decade,
   qd.id as master_difficulty,
   qq.IsEditable, qq.IsDeletable,
   qq.FilePath,
   SUBSTRING(
          qq.FilePath, 
          (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) + 2),
          (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('.', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath))) -1 ) as fpath
  -- (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('.', reverse(qq.FilePath)) as positionoflastdot),
   --(len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) as positionoflastslash),
   from Olddatabase.dbo.QuizQuestion qq
   left join Olddatabase.dbo.QuizQuestionType qqt on qq.QuizQuestionTypeID = qqt.QuizQuestionTypeID
   left join Olddatabase.dbo.QuizQuestionDifficulty qqd on qq.QuizQuestionDifficultyID = qqd.QuizQuestionDifficultyID
   left join Olddatabase.dbo.QuizQuestionCategory qqc on qq.QuizQuestionCategoryID = qqc.QuizQuestionCategoryID
   left join Olddatabase.dbo.QuizQuestionDecade qqdc on qq.QuizQuestionDecadeID = qqdc.QuizQuestionDecadeID
   left join Olddatabase.dbo.QuizQuestionCategory qqmc on qq.MasterCategoryID = qqmc.MasterQuestionCategoryID
   left join Newdatabase.dbo.QuizCategories cat on qqc.CategoryName = cat.name
   left join Newdatabase.dbo.QuizDifficulties qd on qd.id = qq.MasterDifficultyID
   where qq.MasterCategoryID is not null
   ) as questions
left join Newdatabase.dbo.Media2 media on media.name = replace(fpath, 'quiz','')
```

i cant really change to structure of the tables as the software relies heavily on it, and changing it manually would be painful and time consuming as there are over 2000 audio/images questions

i'm just getting my head around SQL databases and queries but this has stopped me dead from progressing.

any help changing this above query or creating something entirely different would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I **think** I understand your question. Using the proper table and column names consistently throughout would be very helpful—unless you did, in which case I am very confused. Either way, please provide sets of sample data with table and column names that match the query you provided.

Comment: No problem ill sort this out tomorrow when im back in the office and replace the examples with snippets from the actual tables.

Comment: @Philip Kelley changes to question made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at it, the code seems properly structured. Faced with something like this, I’d “cut down” the query to only the relevant parts, and debug from there, tossing in extra lines like those you currently have commented out to review the parts of the function calls being returned. Pick it part, look at all th details, and you’ll eventually figure out what’s not lining up. The following should work as an initial "minimum query":

```
select 
   qquestions.FilePath
  ,questions.fpath
  ,media.id as mediaid
 from (--  Build the necessary filepath.  Running just the subquery can help figure things out too
       select
         qq.FilePath
        ,SUBSTRING(
              qq.FilePath
             ,(len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath)) + 2)
             ,(len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('.', reverse(qq.FilePath))) - (len(qq.FilePath) - charindex('/', reverse(qq.FilePath))) -1 ) as fpath
       from Olddatabase.dbo.QuizQuestion qq
       where qq.MasterCategoryID is not null
   ) as questions
left join Newdatabase.dbo.Media2 media
  on media.name = replace(fpath, 'quiz','')
```

Mess with this and it should be easier to figre things out.

Bonus advice: code like

```
CASE 
   WHEN qq.createdDate is not NULL THEN qq.createdDate
      ELSE GETDATE()
END as createdDate,
```

can be replaced with the shorter and more legible form

```
isnull(qq.createdDate, getdate())  createdDate,
```

Comment: after playing around with the above query i am always getting an    `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function`  the cause is the second len line with as fpath at the end  and its the -1 thats returning a negative value and i think this is because also in the old questions table there are questions without a filepath and have a null value. if i change it to 0 it will run but the filename  has a full stop '.' at the end which is stopping it joining to the new questions database media 2 table. is there a way around this to stop it returning a negative value

Comment: This issue has been sorted the code was absolutely spot on as you said. The problem was within the old questions table itself your query above helped me locate a rogue null value on a questions filepath that was `'Null'`instead of just Null without Apostrophe's.

Comment: Yep, when you can't find problems with the code, reviewing in detail the data you have to work with becomes important. This bit of wisdom is reflected in a mantra I say now and then: Never look at the data (because you won't like what you'll see).